# warning: initialization of 'unsigned char' from 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: arrays, c, struct, initialization

Actually there's no error. Code is working fine, but that warning is annoying me.

```
lib/uwc_event/wifi_event.c: In function 'uwc_wifi_init_sta':
lib/uwc_event/wifi_event.c:33:24: warning: initialization of 'unsigned char' from 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
               .ssid = {(uint8_t *)&WIFI_SSID[0]},
                        ^
lib/uwc_event/wifi_event.c:33:24: note: (near initialization for 'wifi_config.sta.ssid[0]')
lib/uwc_event/wifi_event.c:34:28: warning: initialization of 'unsigned char' from 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
               .password = {(uint8_t *)&WIFI_PASW[0]},
                            ^
lib/uwc_event/wifi_event.c:34:28: note: (near initialization for 'wifi_config.sta.password[0]')
```

And this is the part code where warning show:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
      .sta =
          {
              .ssid = {(uint8_t *)&WIFI_SSID[0]},
              .password = {(uint8_t *)&WIFI_PASW[0]},
              .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH,
          },
  };
```

Where `.ssid` is declared (I'm not sure, see: (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_wifi/include/esp_wifi_types.h)) with:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ssid[32];
    uint8_t password[64];

// another code...
```

`WIFI_SSID` and `WIFI_PASW` are declared by myself with:

```
extern char WIFI_SSID[32];
extern char WIFI_PASW[32];
```

So how do I remove those warning? What makes that warning happen?

Comment: What's the definition of wifi_config.sta.ssid and password?  Error message says it's an unsigned char but not a pointer. It's implementation defined if char is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Not sure I believe that ssid is a single byte.

Comment: It's an array not a pointer.  You need to strcpy instead.

Comment: Wait, I actually bit confused about ```ssid``` and ```password``` type because it's framework definition. Here I show you where it's defined (https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/esp_wifi/include/esp_wifi_types.h) There are two ssid definition. One with ```uint8_t``` and one with ```uint8_t*```

Comment: Since `.ssid` is an array, an initialization like `.ssid = { s0, s1, s2 }` would initialize `.ssid[0]` with `s0`, `.ssid[1]` with `s1`, etc.  So you are attempting to initialize the 0th element of this array, which is of type `uint8_t`, with the expression `(uint8_t *)&WIFI_SSID[0]` which is a pointer.

Comment: It's not possible to compile-time initialize one array with another array.  You will have to initialize it at runtime with `memcpy` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssid` and `password` are arrays so you are trying to initialize the (rhs) address into the first element of an array.  Instead you want to copy the data with for example `strcpy()`:

```
strcpy(wifi_config.sta.ssid, WIFI_SSID);
strcpy(wifi_config.sta.password, WIFI_PASW);
```

Answer (score 2):

The data member `ssid` is declared as an array of objects of the type `uint8_t`

```
uint8_t ssid[32];
```

You are trying to initialize its first element with a pointer

```
.ssid = {(uint8_t *)&WIFI_SSID[0]},
```

The initialization above is equivalent to

```
.ssid = {[0] = (uint8_t *)&WIFI_SSID[0]},
```

That is the element `ssid[0]` is initialized with a pointer.

So the compiler issues a diagnostic message.

The same problem exists with the data member `password`.

To set values of these data members you need to use either `strcpy` if these arrays contain strings

```
extern char WIFI_SSID[32];
extern char WIFI_PASW[32];
```

or `memcpy` if the arrays do not contain strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @AllanWind and @VladfromMoscow, my final code will be:

```
wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
      .sta =
          {
              .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH,
          },
  };

strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.ssid, (char *)&WIFI_SSID[0], 32);
strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.password, (char *)&WIFI_PASW[0], 64);
```

And here the compiler result without warning anymore:

```
 *  Executing task: C:\Users\User\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run 

Processing esp32cam (platform: espressif32; board: esp32cam; framework: espidf)
------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32cam.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (5.0.0+sha.e66e12c) > AI Thinker ESP32-CAM
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)      
PACKAGES:
 - framework-espidf @ 3.40401.0 (4.4.1)
 - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.30300.0 (3.3.0)
 - tool-idf @ 1.0.1
 - tool-mconf @ 1.4060000.20190628 (406.0.0)
 - tool-ninja @ 1.9.0
 - toolchain-esp32ulp @ 1.22851.191205 (2.28.51)
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch3
Reading CMake configuration...
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 7 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
Dependency Graph
|-- esp32-camera @ 2.0.0
|-- uwc_event
|   |-- uwc_cam_cfg
|   |   |-- esp32-camera @ 2.0.0
|   |-- uwc_eol_remover
|   |-- uwc_tag
|   |-- uwc_uart
|   |-- uwc_wifi_cfg
|   |   |-- uwc_tag
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\esp32cam\liba67\uwc_event\wifi_event.o
Archiving .pio\build\esp32cam\liba67\libuwc_event.a
Linking .pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.elf
Retrieving maximum program size .pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.elf
Checking size .pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
RAM:   [=         ]  10.1% (used 33120 bytes from 327680 bytes)
Flash: [=======   ]  72.0% (used 755277 bytes from 1048576 bytes) 
Building .pio\build\esp32cam\firmware.bin
esptool.py v3.3
Creating esp32 image...
Merged 25 ELF sections
Successfully created esp32 image.
================== [SUCCESS] Took 21.36 seconds ==================
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```